# Threading/Function Pointers Error in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am learning about function pointers and thread in C. The following code will create a thread that will read string from user. Then It will print the name which was entered by user on main thread. But I got Segmentation fault: 11

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int agelimit;
char *string1, *string2;
void *getName();
//void (*getAge)();
main(){

    pthread_t thread1,thread2;

    string1 = malloc(1000);
    //scanf("%s",string0);
    pthread_create(&thread1, 0, getName, 0);


    //pthread_create(&thread2, 0, getAge, 0);
    sleep(10);
    printf("name is %s age is",string1);



}
void *getName(){

    int x;
    printf("enter name:");

    scanf("%s",&string1);
}
```

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you warnings about this, get a better one.

Comment: I am using 'gcc version 4.2.1' and it throwed  me 4 warnings !

Comment: And you did what? Ignored them? If you want your code to work, you have to listen to the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your code needs some more improvement/error handling but it seems you need to change the

```
scanf("%s",&string1);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",string1);
```

to get it working now.

Pl. refer the Link for a good tutorial on

[POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

**Explanation:**

string1 is a variable and stored in memory. So it is having a memory address say *a1* (this is the starting address).
Now what is stored in this memory address? This comes from your assignment statement below.

```
string1 = malloc(1000);
```

malloc ->allocates a chunk of 1000 bytes of memory and returns the starting address of the chunk, which is say *p1*.

So now content of the variable string1 is *p1* or in other words the memory cell *a1* is now having *p1*(actually this should not be a single cell but a 4byte/8byte quantity..but I am assuming a single cell for simplicity).

Now what scanf expects as its 2nd argument here?

```
scanf("%s",&string1);

A valid address where it can store the input which it has accepted.

What is that in this example a1 or p1? - It is p1.
```

So when you are giving &string1 as an argument to scanf, you were passing *a1* to scanf ,which is not correct. It should get *p1* to work properly, so you need to pass string1 and not &string1

Hope this explanation helps. In general Pl. refer the c-faq link below, which is very helpful for understanding c concepts
[comp.lang.c Frequently Asked Questions](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: it worked for me. Could you please tell me why '&' made error. Some times putting '&' on char[] worked for me.

Comment: @rakeshNS, Hello Rakesh, I have added the explanation. Pl. see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Threading in general can lead to quirky behaviour with buffered streams, but your code is erroneous, too. `getName` has a wrong signature for `pthread_create` and inside it you're calling `scanf` with conflicting arguments (i.e. "%s" and `char**`).

Consider turning warning levels higher in whatever compiler it is that you're using.